# Download data from the Human Microbiome Project via ascp

Tags: data-download

I have asked this question in [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/281809/), but I am trying here as well as people working with "omics" data might be able to help. I think my issue relates understanding how large data storage on online server works. I am trying to download large data from the Human Microbiome Project. These are available on online server and can be downloaded via aspera (ascp).

I can't figure out the right path to get the data. On [their website](https://www.hmpdacc.org/hmp/resources/download.php), they give an example of command to retreive an example dataset:

```
 ascp -l 100M -QT user@aspera.hmpdacc.org:/ReferenceGenomes/test_genome.tar /path/to/local/directory
```

I executed this, using my own username, from this I am asked my password, and I can authenticate. But then I get the following error:

```
(Error: Server aborted session: No such file or directory)
```

Then, I downloaded the manifest file via the HMP portal. In this manifest, they provide the path to which these files are supposed to be available. I tried to execute again the command with one of those path, provided by the manifest file:

```
ascp -l 100M -QT user@aspera.hmpdacc.org:/files/5a950f27980b5d93e4c16da124000378  /path/to/local/directory
```

I again get the same error of "No such file or directory".

The [full url](http://downloads.hmpdacc.org/data2/hhs/genome/microbiome/wgs/analysis/hmwgsqc/v2/SRS013951.tar.bz2) provided by the manifest

I tried putting different chunks of this address into to ascp command but nothing works. I think there is something I don't understand about how to access the server via aspera and what is expected to go in this path. When I copy paste this url in google, this directly download the file I want. So I'm close, but I need to do it via command line as I need to download hundreds of these files and they are huge (6-10GB each).

How can I download the data of the human microbiome project using ascp?

Comment: Is the manifest file a list of links like you provided? I mean to ask is the manifest file hundreds of lines with a URLs like `http://downloads.hmpdacc.org/data2/hhs/genome/microbiome/wgs/analysis/hmwgsqc/v2/SRS013951.tar.bz2`per line? It would helpful to see the format of the manifest file. The first 5 lines should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

I can't test for ascp because they do not longer support my current setup but you can follow the [FTP instructions](https://www.hmpdacc.org/hmp/resources/ftp_public.php). With FileZilla:

url: public-ftp.ihmpdcc.org

Comment: It looks like @CAsimonet has already gone through the instructions on the website and is have fine-tuned issues with getting a lot of specific files.